# NSDateFormatter date format string

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an odd issue with an NSDateFormatter, I am passing the following string as a date format "dd/MM/yy"

If I enter  50 for the year I get a conversion to 1950 however anything below that for instance 49 results in 2049. Any ideas how I can remedy this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Remedy what? How the date formatter is trying it's best to overcome the ambiguity of the format dd/MM/yy? Even as I read your question I don't know what you want. Do you want the year 50 to be 2050 or 1850, or is it about early Christians and you want just 50AD? You simply need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to force a four digit response (or programmatically prepend two digits of "19") to wherever you're drawing your string from. Lots of people are using dates in the near to mid-term future like "12/21/12" (end of the Mayan Calendar era) so it's natural that a 2 digit year assumes 2000+ for digits 1-50 and 1999- for digits (50-99).

I'm also seeing a number of Google hits on the keyword terms "NSDateFormatter" & "century", b.t.w.

Comment: Adding a prefix and changing the format to yyyy solved my issue. Thanks.